# I want to read a "Game of life" .txt file into a 2D array c++

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

This is what i have until now:

```
bool read_universe_file (ifstream& inputfile, Cell universe [Rows][Columns])   
{
     int i,j = 0;
     string filename;
     cout << "Enter the name of the file yo want to use: ";
     cin >> filename;
     ifstream myfile(filename.c_str());

     while(infile)
     {
        //char a = infile.get();
        char a;
        infile >> a;
        universe[i][j] = (Cell)a;
        i++;
        if(a == '\n')
        {
            j++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It does run but it doesn't work..

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work".

Comment: "It doesn't work" because ....?

Comment: You miss validation of the file input against the your data format (an array Rows x Columns) - Also you should not use'\n' as a condition to advance to the next row (it's a white-space character, never showing up in formatted input)

Comment: i dont know why it doesnt work; it starts running and (i think) after one loop it says looking for a solution and the compiler stops

Answer (score 0):

Say cin >> noskipws; at the beginning of your function. This will avoid formatted input from skipping whitespaces. I guess this is the intended way of operation in your case.

Regards